# Received data are correct on scope not in program

Tags: arduino, spi

I use Arduino `shiftIn` instruction to receive data from a MLX90316.
It uses one wire for MOSI an MISO.
Data consists of 4 bytes (2+2)
First 2 bytes are an angle value. Second 2 bytes ares the reversed value of angle (1st complement)
First 2 bytes are correct on scope and program (0x00 and 0x22)
**Second 2 bytes are correct on scope (0xFF and 0XDD), but are frequently (not always) wrong in program (0xFF and 0xDC or 0xFF and 0xCC...)**

In fact only last byte is sometimes wrong when I print it.

I have tried to change Serial speed to 9600 bps (same result)
I have tried to change delayMicroseconds value before last shiftIn (same result)

```
/* MLX90316 Rotary Position Sensor */

int readAngle();

int pinSS = 10;  // Green Wire
int pinDATA = 11; // Yellow Wire
int pinSCK = 13; // Grey Wire

unsigned int r1=0;
unsigned int r2=0;
unsigned int r3=0;
unsigned int r4=0;

int angle;

void setup(){
  delayMicroseconds(16000);  // 16ms slave start-up
  pinMode(pinSS,OUTPUT);  // Pin Slave Select
  pinMode(pinSCK, OUTPUT); // Pin Clock
  digitalWrite(pinSS, HIGH); // de-select chip
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("MLX90316 Rotary Position Sensor");
}

void loop() {
  angle = readAngle();
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("r1=");Serial.println(r1,HEX);
  Serial.print("r2=");Serial.println(r2,HEX);
  Serial.print("r3=");Serial.println(r3,HEX);
  Serial.print("r4=");Serial.println(r4,HEX);

  delay(10000);
}

int readAngle() {
  // Start with clock LOW
  digitalWrite(pinSCK, LOW);

  // Data pin in write mode
  pinMode(pinDATA, OUTPUT);

  // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
  digitalWrite(pinSS, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(30);

  // Send START bytes
  shiftOut(pinDATA, pinSCK, MSBFIRST, 0xAA);
  delayMicroseconds(25);
  shiftOut(pinDATA, pinSCK, MSBFIRST, 0xFF);
  delayMicroseconds(30);  // 30 us between START bytes and DATA

  // Data pin in read mode
  pinMode(pinDATA, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Receive data
  r1 = shiftIn(pinDATA, pinSCK, MSBFIRST);
  delayMicroseconds(25);
  r2 = shiftIn(pinDATA, pinSCK, MSBFIRST);
  delayMicroseconds(25);
  r3 = shiftIn(pinDATA, pinSCK, MSBFIRST);
  delayMicroseconds(30);
  r4 = shiftIn(pinDATA, pinSCK, MSBFIRST);

  // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pinSS, HIGH);
}
```

I expect the output of 0x00 0x22 0xFF 0xDD

Comment: "correct on scope" - for the used polarity and phase?

Comment: Yes. CPOL=0 and CPHA=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which Arduino you are using but the shift in and out functions are very simple software implementations.

```
uint8_t shiftIn(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder) {
    uint8_t value = 0;
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
            value |= digitalRead(dataPin) << i;
        else
            value |= digitalRead(dataPin) << (7 - i);
        digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The MLX90316 allows only a clock speed of 145kHz, so this direct port access could be too fast and the data is not ready when you read it.
But since you have a scope available you could simply check that timing and write your own `shiftIn` if necessary.

I think this "version" should work for your chip (untested)

```
uint8_t shiftIn2(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin) {
    uint8_t value = 0;
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(4);
        digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
        value |= digitalRead(dataPin) << (7 - i);
        delayMicroseconds(4);           
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Right. I just looked at write_shift.c because I wondered about the timings, and this is just ... I'm surprised it ever works for anyone.

Comment: I think it works as long as the controller is not to fast :)

Comment: On scope I see one period=15.2us. So freq is 65.8kHz (not too fast).  I don't understand why this happen only with last byte. Furthermore, wrong values are only 0xCC, 0xDC and 0XCD

Comment: Bingo! It works fine with shiftIn2. And clock frequency is 52.41kHz